# How to disable workspace stages in Typo3 4.5?

Tags: cms, typo3

I upgraded our site to Typo3 4.5. The workspace extension has changed significantly. We have a very flat organizational structure, without separate editors, reviewers and publishers. Our editors should edit in the Draft workspace, and then be able to directly publish. They can do this right now, by clicking the checkboxes in the Workspace module, and selecting "Publish to LIVE". However, when they mistakenly click "send to next stage", they will not be able to publish it themselves anymore. Only admin will be able to do that in our configuration. Can I disable this stage stuff, because we do not need it at all?

Comment: Just uninstall the whole workspace module

Comment: well, i still want to have ONE barrier for the users, so that they do not edit the live page directly...

Comment: I am having the exact same issue - anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem, Claus? I followed Robert's advice so far, just disabled workspace altogether. Not good, but at least we can now publish stuff rather than having to wait for the admin to accept changes.